# Visit site as a different computer

Tags: web

How can I visit a website once and act as if it was my first time there, the same as visiting that site as if i were on a different computer but with the same computer? Ive tried things like vpn and proxies but they dont seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Delete all your cookies, which are used to identify your PC.
2. Use a browser that helps prevent [fingerprinting](https://blokt.com/guides/browser-fingerprinting), such as [TOR](https://www.torproject.org/).
3. To avoid your IP address or location being shown by your ISP, use a VPN. As you state, a VPN is not enough, by itself, to prevent your browser leaking identifying information.

Note that some sites restrict users by location, so a VPN may prevent the site from opening.

Check info being leaked at a sit such as [Panopticlick](https://panopticlick.eff.org/) or [AmIUnique](https://amiunique.org/).